# woocommerce how add custom data to cart with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add custom data to woocommerce fragment with ajax, but I don't know how to pass it properly. I found topic with similar question, but it doesn't work for me.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632687/woocommerce-ajax-add-to-cart-with-additional-custom-data](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

this is my jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisbutton = $(this),
                $form = thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
                id = thisbutton.val(),
                product_qty = $form.find('input[name=quantity]').val() || 1,
                product_id = $form.find('input[name=product_id]').val() || id,
                variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;
    var data = {
            action: 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_sku: '',
            quantity: product_qty,
            variation_id: variation_id,
            name: 'Tom',
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (response) {
                thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
            }, 
            success: function (response) { 
                if (response.error & response.product_url) {
                    window.location = response.product_url;
                    return;
                } else { 
                    $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, thisbutton]);
                } 
                console.log( wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url, data);
            }, 
        }); 
     }); 
});
```

this is my function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');          
function ql_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {  

    $product_id = apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
    $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id); 
    $cart_item_data['name'] = 'Tom';
    


    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) { 
        do_action('ql_woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);

            if ('yes' === get_option('ql_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) { 
                wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true); 
            } 

            WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments(); 
            } else { 
                $data = array( 
                    'error' => true,
                    'product_url' => apply_filters('ql_woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));
                echo wp_send_json($data);
            }
            wp_die();
        }
```

I try to pass custom data to woocommerce fragment with ajax, but I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: no errors, just not able to add custom cart_item_data

Comment: First we have to detect which part isn't working, Javascript or php. Is your javascript sending a request? You can see that in the network tab in the browser dev tools. If the request isn't triggered then we can focus on Javascript part.